# How to configure listeners in a spring batch job in a grails project?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-batch

I use spring batch in a grails project, and i installed a grails plugin to get it work : grails-spring-batch

I implemtented a simple job, with a reader, a processor and a writer, and it works fine.

But i would like to add listeners to my job steps (reader, processor and writer), in order to handle errors nicely.

But i can't get to make my listeners beeing used ! I think i may be misusing the dsl used to define beans. With different tries on the dsl, i have sometimes errors at runtime, or sometimes no errors but the listener is not used.

Do you know if the grails-spring-batch plugin currently allow to define listeners ? If yes, how does it work ?

here is my spring batch conf, which uses the DSL the grails plugin provides:

```
batch.job(id: 'simpleJob') {
    batch.step(id: 'myStep') {
        batch.tasklet{
            batch.chunk(
                    reader: 'myReader',
                    processor: 'myProcessor',
                    writer: 'myWriter',
                    'commit-interval': 1,
                    listeners:
                            batch.listener(
                                    ref: "myReaderListener"
                            )

            )
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: a simple solution i did not think about : make my reader implements **ItemReadListener,** which brings the **onError** method, which is exactly what i try to do.

But if the need is to put the listener logic in another bean, my question still stands.

Comment: Shouldn't listeners be defined outside the chunk but inside the tasklet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the listener should be configured on the `tasklet`.  It should also be in a `listeners` block. Try this:

```
batch.job(id: 'simpleJob') {
    batch.step(id: 'myStep') {
        batch.tasklet {
            batch.chunk(
                reader: 'myReader',
                processor: 'myProcessor',
                writer: 'myWriter',
                'commit-interval': 1)
             batch.listeners {
                 batch.listener(ref: 'myReaderListener')
             }
         }
    }
}
```